Missing Data on Survival Analysis
I want to run a survival analysis (say, Cox model) with time of origin at birth and a disease (say, cancer) as the event,. Covariates are around 5 demographic variables (age, sex, etc.).
The problem is that for some samples (10 percent or so),. For some patients, the time is missing. Specifically, there are two variables: cancer (or not) and the year of diagnosis (if cancer=Y). For 10% of the samples, cancer=Y and year are missing. So if a person is 55, we know that he had cancer before age 55 but don't know the exact year.
Is there anything I can do other than delete all samples with missing data? I have around 200 patients and 1000 controls. I am willing to assume MAR (since there's no reason to assume otherwise).
Also, if anyone can recommend a book on missing data, I will deeply appreciate it (I have a graduate degree in statistics but know nothing about missing data methodology other than EM).

Say more on what you mean that the "exact time" is missing. In fact, the exact time of all cancers is missing - we only know of their existence upon diagnostic confirmation. Even if you rewind time to first screen detection, a time preceded then at which the cancerous cells existed. This is a matter of days for aggressive cancers, but a matter of years for, e.g.  DCIS.

"I know that they do have cancer, but the exact time is missing." Presumably you mean diagnosis as the event. In principle, you could consider those individuals to have left-censored event times. That is, you only have an upper limit to the event time (as opposed to only a lower limit for the right censoring that's more typical in survival analysis). I'd suggest that you edit the question to say more about what you are trying to accomplish with this study. Patient/control comparison can be tricky, and using birth as the time origin can lead to left-truncation issues.

@EdM I think the OP may be interested in a case cohort design, but would require some complicated weights to offset selection of controls. Furthermore, a patient known to have cancer but not when sounds more like an interval censoring problem. One which can be solved with imputation.

I have edited the problem. I thought about left censoring, in which O=max(T, C) where C is the censoring time and T is the event time. I am hesitating because it doesn't seem that T and C are independent. Also, can you give an example of how using birth as time origin leads to left truncation issues? Thank you!

This answer to what might be a related question of yours outlines left truncation, with a reference/link to the classic Klein and Moeschberger text on censoring and truncation. This question illustrates, for a Kaplan-Meier analysis, what can happen at the earliest left truncation times; estimates can be iffy as there are typically few individuals at risk in your data until later.

Stef van Buuren's Flexible Imputation of Missing Data is a superb, freely available resource. Section 3.7.3 covers "Censored, truncated and rounded data."
